# List of uncommon Numpy operators (<<, >>, &, |, ~, @, etc) and what they do

Tags: python, numpy, operators

Until recently I didn't even know that the `@` Numpy operator existed (apparently it's the binary matrix multiplication operator). Is there a comprehensive list of these less-seen Numpy operators and their behavior? I've searched around google and the official docs, but I'm having trouble turning up comprehensive information. Can anyone supply a list and/or link to a definitive one? Anything that covers `@` and other infrequently used operators (like the bitwise operators) in depth would be great.

#### Edit

I want a complete list of all of the operators that can be used with Numpy arrays. I am not that interested in the fine details of the implementation of `~`, so I've removed extraneous details.

Comment: `numpy` does not add any operators.  It's the Python interpreter that recognizes operators (including `@`) and delegates the action to a method (e.g. `__add__`).  The `add` for Python lists and strings is different from the add for numbers.  Here's a `numpy` list: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arithmetic-matrix-multiplication-and-comparison-operations

Comment: @hpaulj Ah! Perfect. Thanks for pointing that section of the docs out.

Comment: The `numpy` implementation of operators will depend on the `dtype`.  Typically `numpy` performs a element-wise action (using `broadcasting` rules).  For example `+` (`add`) works for numeric arrays, but not for string dtypes.  `object` dtype is even more complicated.

Comment: `@`, `matmul`, is unusual.  It's the only recently added operator, and isn't implemented for Python scalars.